# How to gain confidence during a large, complex merge?

Tags: git, merging

I recently finished a large merge with many complex conflicts that needed to be resolved.  The branches had been separate from one another for several months while different teams contributed to each branch.  Ideally the two branches would have been kept in sync with one another, but that did not happen in this case for whatever reason.  I was then asked to merge the branches.  Many changes were needed to resolve the conflicts and by the end it was unclear whether any of the original behaviour from either branch had been lost.

I used the technique outlined in my response below to gain more confidence that all of the behaviour had been retained but it was a tedious and complicated manual process (it did work though and caught several instances in which changes *had* been lost).

**Are there any other techniques or tools I can use to check this more easily in future situations where a large merge cannot be avoided?**  Ideally they would be avoided by following better practices but sometimes that is out of a developer's control.

I have tried using git's `range-diff` command but wasn't able to understand the output or how to confidently tune the `creation-factor` parameter.

Comment: A pragmatic non-answer for you -- git-imerge.  It is like power steering for merges (and rebases).

It even supports conflict resolution by multiple parties -- you can assign conflicts to the developers of the commits that conflict.

Confidence in the whole comes from increased confidence in a bunch of much smaller parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “diff of diffs” technique is a process that can be useful for ensuring that the behaviour from two contributing branches has been preserved during a difficult merge requiring complex conflict resolutions.  Oftentimes during such merges, while making many changes to resolve the conflicts, it can become unclear which contributor content has been preserved and which content has inadvertently been lost.  This technique helps a developer to gain confidence that the unique behaviour introduced by both contributors is preserved during the merge.

#### Technique and example

The technique uses a number of diffs created after merging that assess preservation of changes made since the two contributors diverged from a common ancestor.

In the example below, branches A and B diverged from one another at commit `D`.  Development happened along each branch, altering many files, until branch A was at commit `H` and branch B was at commit `K`.  At that point, the developer wished to merge the content and chose to merge branch B into A, resulting in a new commit `L` on branch A containing the merged content and any resultant conflict resolutions.

[image: Before merge]
*Before merge*

[image: After merge]
*After merge*

One can also visualize the history of these branches as a rectangle.
[image: Migration rectangle]

The goal of this technique is to ensure that the contributions of branch A (commits `D` thru `H`) and on branch B (commits `D` thru `K`) are both preserved in the merge output `L`, minus any changes that were necessary to resolve merge conflicts.  To achieve this goal, follow this process:

##### Check that the contributions from branch A have been preserved in the merge output

[image: Branch A check]

1. Create `DiffLK` and `DiffHD`.  `DiffHD` represents the contributions from branch A and `DiffLK` represents how many of them were preserved through the merge (we strive for 100% minus any necessary discrepancies due to merge conflict resolutions).
2. Compare the output of both diffs side-by-side.

   1. If an area of the diff outputs is not exactly equivalent and the discrepancy is not due to the way a merge conflict was resolved, then a contribution from branch A was accidentally lost during the merge and it must be re-added to preserve the behaviour of branch A.  Modify `L` as needed to reflect the changes in `DiffHD` until `DiffLK` matches `DiffHD` in that area once again.
   2. Repeat until `DiffLK` and `DiffHD` fully match with the only exceptions being conflict areas that were manually resolved during the merge.

##### Check that the contributions from branch B have been preserved in the merge output

[image: Branch B check]

1. Create `DiffLH` and `DiffKD`.  `DiffKD` represents the contributions from branch B and `DiffLH` represents how many of them were preserved through the merge (we strive for 100% minus any necessary discrepancies due to merge conflict resolutions).
2. Compare the output of both diffs side-by-side.

   1. If an area of the diff outputs is not exactly equivalent and the discrepancy is not due to the way a merge conflict was resolved, then a contribution from branch B was accidentally lost during the merge and it must be re-added to preserve the behaviour of branch B.  Modify `L` as needed to reflect the changes in `DiffKD` until `DiffLH` matches `DiffKD` in that area once again.
   2. Repeat until `DiffLH` and `DiffKD` fully match with the only exceptions being conflict areas that were manually resolved during the merge.

#### Theory

Why does this technique work and how does it give us confidence that all content has been migrated?  Let’s dive in.

The merge initially attempts to copy commits `I`, `J`, and `K` from branch B onto branch A as `I'`, `J'`, and `K'` as shown below.  The developer may then have to manually resolve conflicts and may accidentally lose some content during the merge due to the amount of content being migrated and the complexity of the conflict resolutions.

[image: After merge, with error and conflict resolution terms added]

`L`, the output of the merge, can then be expressed as

```
Equation 1: L = (A + B + C + D) + (E + F + G + H) + (I' + J' + K') + r + e
```

where

- `L` is the result of the merge.
- `(A + B + C + D)` are the ancestor commits made before branches A and B diverged.  `D` is the last common ancestor of both branches.
- `(E + F + G + H)` are the contributions from branch A.
- `(I' + J' + K')` are the contributions from branch B.
- `r` represents the manual “resolutions“ required to handle any conflicts during the merge.
- `e` represents the “error” of the merge (i.e. any content that was accidentally lost).

Notably, in the original example above, the following simplifications were made

- `DiffHD` was the simplification of `(E + F + G + H) - (A + B + C + D)`.
- `DiffKD` was the simplification of `(I + J + K) - (A + B + C + D)`.
- `DiffLK` was the simplification of `L - (A + B + C + D) - (I + J + K)`.
- `DiffLH` was the simplification of `L - (A + B + C + D) - (E + F + G + H)`.

We then assert two things: (1) `DiffLK` is equivalent to `DiffHD` plus the conflict resolutions `r` and (2) `DiffLH` is equivalent to `DiffKD` plus the conflict resolutions `r`.  The first assertion essentially claims that the output contains only branch A content plus any conflict resolutions and the second assertion claims the same but for branch B.

```
Assertion 1: DiffLK = DiffHD + r
Assertion 2: DiffLH = DiffKD + r
```

Simplifying these two assertions yields

```
DiffLK - DiffHD - r = 0
DiffLH - DiffKD - r = 0
DiffLK - DiffHD - r = DiffLH - DiffKD - r
```

We then assert that the sum of the differences between these diffs is the error of the merge `e`, which we want to be 0.  Essentially this is claiming that anything in the diffs that is not content from branch A, branch B, or a conflict resolution must be an error (which, again, we want to be 0).

```
Assertion 3: (DiffLK - DiffHD - r) + (DiffLH - DiffKD - r) = e = 0
```

Expanding Assertion 3 with the various diff simplifications and re-simplifying yields

```
/* Starting from Assertion 3 */
  (DiffLK - DiffHD - r)
+ (DiffLH - DiffKD - r) = e = 0

/* Term substitution */
  ((L - (A + B + C + D) - (I + J + K)) - ((E + F + G + H) - (A + B + C + D)) - r)
+ ((L - (A + B + C + D) - (E + F + G + H)) - ((I + J + K) - (A + B + C + D)) - r) = e = 0

/* Distributing sign */
  (L - (A + B + C + D) - (I + J + K) - (E + F + G + H) + (A + B + C + D) - r)
+ (L - (A + B + C + D) - (E + F + G + H) - (I + J + K) + (A + B + C + D) - r) = e = 0

/* Canceling terms */
  (L - (I + J + K) - (E + F + G + H) - r)
+ (L - (E + F + G + H) - (I + J + K) - r) = e = 0

/* Aggregating terms */
2*L - 2*(I + J + K) - 2*(E + F + G + H) - 2*r = e = 0

/* Factoring out common multiples */
L - (I + J + K) - (E + F + G + H) - r = e/2 = 0/2 = 0

/* Finally, the merge output should only be the contributions from both branches and any conflict resolutions. */
L = (I + J + K) + (E + F + G + H) + r
```

Therefore, in order for the merge error `e` to be 0 (i.e. no content lost), the merge output `L` must be adjusted by the developer until it strictly equals the contributions from branch A `(E + F + G + H)`, branch B `(I + J + K)`, and any necessary conflict resolutions `r`.  If any other content exists in `L`, then the error term `e` cannot disappear and thus error has been introduced into the merge.

Therefore, in order to accomplish the goal of reducing merge error `e` to 0, Assertions 1, 2, and 3 must be upheld, yielding the technique outlined above where one performs two diff-of-diffs with the only permissible deviations being manual conflict resolutions `r`.

Comment: Supposedly, git's `range-diff` command was built to automate this "diff-of-diffs" technique and notify the caller if any content was lost but the documentation is sparse and playing around with the command was confusing.  Does anyone understand how it works?

Answer (score 6):

It is better to learn to avoid complexity than it is to put effort in becoming better at dealing with it (unless the way of dealing with it is by avoiding it). What you definitely shouldn't do is take an even more complicated route to fix the less complicated issue, because then you've made things worse, not better.

To this end, I've changed my opinion on clever solutions to some degree. As a junior developer, I tried to cleverly solve things as best as I could. As a senior/lead developer, I now realize that clever solutions tend to lack in future maintainability, and I instead design *elegant* solutions, specifically focused on ensuring that they are as easy to comprehend in the future by others as they were when designing the solution.

The answer you posted to your own question is convoluted to say the least. I've tried reading it and even just the explanation is so prohibitively complex that my mind immediately backs out. There's no gold to be found in that swamp, there are significantly easier answers that resolve this issue.

**Firstly**, merge frequently.

Don't let diff sizes grow to an unmanageable amount. Given the same amount of changes, it is better to merge them in 10 discrete steps than to do it all at once.
Even though you're usually going to be resolving as many conflicts, possibly even slightly more (if the same thing was changed more than once), the cognitive load of every individual merge will be significantly lower and you will be less likely to make mistakes or fail to spot issues.

To reuse your diagram:

```
Don't do this:
A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H___L (Branch A)
       \         /
        \_I_J_K_/ (Branch B)

Do this:
A_B_C_D_E____F____G_H_________KGH (Branch A)
       \    \    \     \     /
        \_I_IE_J_JF_K___KGH_/ (Branch B)
```

The cadence of the A-to-B merges is arbitrary and depends on how often A tends to change. For most teams, merging two or three times a week is usually sufficient. I tend to do it daily in the morning, when I've heard of a large commit being made to A, or inbetween discrete tasks on my B feature development.

The most important A-to-B merge is the one right before the B-to-A merge. The main idea here is that you want to experience your merge conflicts (and the potential issue from having made mistakes) in your feature branch, not in your main shared branch.

Of course, it's possible that by the time you resolve the KGH merge, there might've been another commit on A, but this is a numbers game. The odds of that being a significant commit that causes a complex issue for your B-to-A merge are low, because you've already resolved all other prior changes that could've caused conflicts.

**Secondly**, back your code using tests.

Tests specifically allow you to run them and ensure that the behavior has not been changed. If you perform a merge, and both the tests from your changeset and the tests from the merged changeset still pass (just like they did before you merged), you can be relatively confident that you didn't make a mistake. That's not an ironclad guarantee, but it's as close to a reliable confirmation as you're going to get.

*The logical tip here is to not merge work that contains broken tests.*

**Thirdly**, generally try to avoid any significant parallel work in the same region of your codebase.

This isn't *always* feasible, but the frequency of parallel work that causes merge conflicts can be mitigated in two ways:

**1** - When your coding standards are clean enough, you will generally be able to avoid collisions as much as possible. I'm specifically looking at SRP, OCP and DI here (the SO--D from SOLID) as they are key principles in keeping code components as discrete as is reasonably possible.

**2** - When planning the work for a given sprint, try to not assign work in the same region to several developers. Only assign one developer to a given story/feature. When dealing with epics, try to tackle them in a way that parallel work occurs on parallel components, not the kind of components where the first depends on the second.

Comment: A large merge typically often contains code which will change behaviour; including new and/or modified tests. While one indeed shouldn't merge work which contain broken tests, one should not assume that if no tests broke, the merge succeeded. If you managed to drop a patch which both changed behaviour and added a test for this, the tests will still succeed, but the merged code doesn't do what it supposed to do.

Comment: I agree with your advice about avoiding complex merges and my team strives to follow them.  However, in a real dev environment, in-progress work can remain undelivered for many reasons (shifting priorities, slow code reviews, long development timelines, etc), people can forget to add unit tests, etc.  Your advice certainly helps to prevent tricky merges most of the time but there are times when they will still occur.  Your advice is valuable in general but does not answer the question of how to handle inevitable complex merges.  Do you have advice for handling those situations?

Comment: @EricSchnipke Complex merges are not inevitable. The things you present as inevitable facts of life are simply not that common in an environment with a healthy dev culture, and they should not be treated like things you are forced to live with. Stale code is problematic code (where merge conflicts exist, since the rest of the code is clearly evolving and the stale code isn't). Code going stale should be avoided at all costs, and for the rare circumstance where it is justified the effort of constantly merging into the stale branch to keep it from going stale becomes a necessary evil.

Comment: @EricSchnipke _"Do you have advice for handling those situations?"_ **Don't.** You're trying to treat the symptom instead of the disease. It will not cure the patient. Take a step back and consider what the actual cause of the symptoms is and tackle that.

Comment: @EricSchnipke Slow code reviews means either they're not being done with enough priority and making code go stale, your devs are delivering low quality work in need of many fixes, or your features are way too big to review in a timely manner. Long development timelines are also an indication of features that are way too big. What's causing you to shift priorities? What has caused you to no longer want to deliver on your commitment? That's a problem. You should start on something only if you actually intend to work at delivering it, and letting half-work go stale should be unacceptable.

Comment: @Abigail Hence "not an ironclad guarantee". If you include scenarios where entire changesets are dropped in a consistent manner that entirely removes the change with otherwise no ill effects, then the only remaining solutions are manually retesting all the application features or manually re-vetting the entire test suite so that it can do it for you. Not what you should be basing your daily practice on, and OP's question seems very much rooted in the day to day activities causing the issues that led to this question.

Comment: @Flater I agree with much of what you're saying but if an organization hasn't yet arrived in a place where development is happening according to best practices, then it is highly likely that an unwieldy merge will happen at some point (again, until best practices can be adopted).  What should a developer who must operate in that environment do in the meantime to merge with confidence?  _That_ is what this question is attempting to address.  Best practices can prevent the issue in the long term but until a team gets there, unwieldy merges can happen and they must be delivered with confidence.

Comment: @Abigail If you cannot assume that passing tests means the merge succeeded, you need more tests.

Comment: @EricSchnipke I do believe that you are genuine in your assertion that you're trying to make it work temporarily. But I am also genuine in my assertion that if you provide a half-assed temporary solution, you will deincentivize the path to a full-assed solution. As a consultant who was often brought in to right the wrongs in a project, it is painstakingly clear that companies that took shortcuts in the past will take them again. It is better to take time to do it the right way and move things around, than it is to litter the road with temporary solutions and risk them becoming the new normal.

Comment: @Flater we may be talking past one another.  You are advocating for organizational change to eliminate the possibility of large merges _in the future_ (with which I agree).  _This_ question is about offering a solution to developers who _currently_ find themselves in the position of having to confidently deliver a large, messy merge.  They cannot change the past or how that large merge built up and yet must still somehow deliver it.  Do you have a solution?  If not, then I know that mine, while complicated, does work and is sound in its theory.

Comment: @Flater I created this question to (1) offer my (albeit complicated) solution to developers who may be in a bind and need help, (2) elicit other approaches from the community to see if I could learn anything, and (3) possibly learn about git's sparsely documented `range-diff` command which purports to automate the solution I outlined in my answer.  This question is _not_ about how to avoid large merges but rather how to handle them with confidence if you have no choice.

Comment: @EricSchnipke: The issue is that providing a solution tends to imply (or rather be inferred as, willingly or not) _condoning_ it as a valid approach; hence this answer to act as a reminder that it is not a reasonable status quo. By all means, leave your answer up, but I maintain the necessity of my answer as a counterbalance to it. I'm also not quite sure if your critique of my answer applies to all of it. Merging frequently is a trivial solution to implement and would already mitigate most of the problems. Yes, the last two points require more organizational change.

Comment: @Flater I do thank you for your detailed response though.  It is good advice for developers on how to avoid large merges _in the future_ (if they can change their organization's practices) and I hope that it helps someone.